# Problem in java ftp code

Tags: java, ftp

i'm getting error in java ftp code.

SimpleFTP could not request passive mode.
i copied this code from net. but it's not working

```
    sendLine("PASV");
    String response = readLine();
    System.out.println(response);
    System.out.println(response);
    if (!response.startsWith("227")) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP could not request passive mode: " + response);
    }
```

Comment: what is the error ? u have given no information ?

Comment: This could be the full source: http://www.silversurferslab.com/blogs/1/java-simple-ftp-client-class-26.html

Comment: it shows "SimpleFTP could not request passive mode"

Comment: It should have printed the `response` too. Please provide **full** error messages to make live easier for those who want to help.

Comment: hi..Andreas_D.. i use the same code u gave. but it throws an error "SimpleFTP could not request passive mode"

Comment: i'm using net beans s/w to run this code. bec i'm adding this code inside my projects.. i'm getting message in putput window as "SimpleFTP could not request passive mode:"
I'm new to this java ftp.

Comment: OK, so now it looks like, the response is an empty string.

Comment: BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        
        sendLine("PASV");
        String response = readLine();
        System.out.println("here");
        System.out.println(response);
        if (!response.startsWith("227")) {
            throw new IOException("SimpleFTP could not request passive mode: " + response);
        }

o/p:
here
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
SimpleFTP could not request passive mode: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're able to connect to the ftp server - otherwise you had received IOExceptions or NullPointerExceptions much earlier.

Problem is, that you can't establish a passive mode connection. If the server is a standard product, then I assume, it would respond correctly with a `227` message.

If I had to debug, I'd start with the following:

1. use a normal shell based ftp client and try to enter passive mode manually. Maybe you get a different response, maybe the server just sends one empty line before the real message
2. use a network sniffer like wireshark to monitor traffic.
3. try to connect to a different ftp server
4. check firewall settings - those may block passive mode because it uses different ports

Comment: i got it Andreas.. Actually problem is in my server as u told. But my in clients server the code is working well. thanks for your effort..

Answer (score 1):

start a command line ftp client with no arguments. Issue the `debug` command to enable display of protocol messages and the `passive` command to set passive mode. (**Note:** the windows command line ftp does not support passive mode!) Use the `open` command to connect to a host. You'll be prompted if you need to log in. Issue the `ls` command to get a directory listing.

Through all of this, the client will display the messages sent and received. There is probably some message variant that your code is not handling. For example, the SimpleFTP code [here](http://www.silversurferslab.com/blogs/1/java-simple-ftp-client-class-26.html) does not handle multi-line responses. See [RFC-959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) § 4.2: FTP Responses.

One embedded system I work with responds to a successful login with:

```
220-Setting memory limit to 1024+1024kbytes
220-Local time is now 10:33 and the load is 1.36.
220 You will be disconnected after 1800 seconds of inactivity.
```

The SimpleFTP code fails because it's expecting a single line beginning with `"220 "`.

Additionally, despite the FTP protocol being quite old, you will encounter quite a few non-conforming implementations.

If you need to do anything more complex than 'put file' or 'get file', take a look at [edtFTPj/Free](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpj/).